# Edit sharepoint list with macro

Tags: excel, sharepoint, vba

I need to change the status and write comments for about 100 lists in SharePoint every week.  I tried to automate it. I know how to open them in edit mode with a macro, but I don't know how to change status or how to write a comment with a macro, any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
Sub TT()
  Dim ie(40) As Object, obj As Object
  Dim cislo As String
  For i = 0 To 40
    If Cells(i + 2, 1).Value = "" Then
      Exit Sub
    End If
    Set ie(i) = CreateObject("Internetexplorer.Application")
    ie(i).Visible = True
    ie(i).Navigate "http://adress of sharepoint list .com"
    Do While ie(i).Busy
    Loop
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I think the link below will help you get oriented. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11426/update-list-from-excel-using-vba

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i dont think, this is what i meant. I dont want to edit lists in excel, but in sharepoint. For example change status, add comments and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These tutorials should give you what you need to know...excellent and well done, they show you how to do it via Listobjects and via SQL

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nM-gq3N6f2E

There is a series of 13 videos.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was so helpful and solved my problems

Comment: @L.Horvath No problem,  please mark it as the right answer if everything worked out for you!